# React router + redux navigating back doesn't call componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

Currently I pre-load data from api in container component's lifecycle method componentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { dept, course } = this.props.routeParams;
  this.props.fetchTimetable(dept, course);
}
```

It is called when user navigates to route `/:dept/:course`, and it works fine, until you navigate from let's say: `/mif/31` to `/mif/33` and then press back button. The component is not actually reinitialized, so the lifecycle method is not called, and the data isn't reloaded.

Is there some sort of way to reload data in this case? Should I maybe use another method of preloading data? I see react router emits `LOCATION_CHANGE` event on any location change, including navigating back, so maybe I can somehow use that?

If it matters, here's is how I implement data loading:

```
import { getTimetable } from '../api/timetable';

export const REQUEST_TIMETABLE = 'REQUEST_TIMETABLE';
export const RECEIVE_TIMETABLE = 'RECEIVE_TIMETABLE';

const requestTimetable = () => ({ type: REQUEST_TIMETABLE, loading: true });
const receiveTimetable = (timetable) => ({ type: RECEIVE_TIMETABLE, loading: false, timetable });

export function fetchTimetable(departmentId, courseId) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestTimetable());
    getTimetable(departmentId, courseId)
      .then(timetable => dispatch(receiveTimetable(timetable)))
      .catch(console.log);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to check if new props (`nextProps`) are same as existing props (`this.props`). Here's relevant code in Redux example: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/e5e608eb87f84d4c6ec22b3b4e59338d234904d5/examples/async/src/containers/App.js#L13-L18

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.dept !== this.props.dept || nextProps.course !== this.props.course) {
    dispatch(fetchTimetable(nextProps.dept, nextProps.course))
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, I was thinking of using this, but didn't look into it more. I didn't want to implement this initially because I thought it would re-fetch data everytime it received props, but I didn't think of checking the props first. Thanks for linking the example, it will be most useful later on too I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I believe the function you are looking for is not componentWillMount but componentWillReceiveProps,

assuming you are passing down variables (like :courseId) from redux router to your component, using setState in componentWillReceiveProps should repaint your component.

Otherwise, you can subscribe to changes in your store: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html

Disclaimer: I probably know less about redux then you.

Comment: I have subscribed to the changes in the store, but the store changes only when the component itself fetches data. It seems that I need to use componentWillMount AND componentWillReceiveProps, because the later doesn't get called on initial rendering.