# While coming back from react navigation componentWillMount doesn't get called

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have used react-navigation and on clicking hardware back button in android, I come back to previous component but componentWillMount doesn't get called. How do I ensure that componentWillMount is called?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514572/react-router-redux-navigating-back-doesnt-call-componentwillmount

Answer (score 1):

componentWillMount will not trigger when you entering new screen / back to the screen.

my solution is using event navigator handler
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=listen-visibility-events-in-onnavigatorevent-handler

you can implement your 'componentWillMount' codes while 'willAppear' event id triggered, see this implementation:

```
export default class ExampleScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
  }
  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    switch(event.id) {
      case '`willAppear`':
       // { implement your code on componentWillMount }
       break;
      case 'didAppear':
        break;
      case 'willDisappear':
        break;
      case 'didDisappear':
        break;
      case 'willCommitPreview':
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For a slightly different problem but I was lead to this page  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle that sorted me out.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer from @bumbur help you? It defines a global variable that tracks if nav state has changed. You could insert a piece of code to see if you're in the specific tab that you are interested in. With that you could trigger a call to componentWillMount() ?

> If you don't want to use redux, this is how you can store globally 
>   information about current route, so you can both detect a tab change 
>   and also tell which tab is now active.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44027538/7388644

```
export default () => <MyTabNav
    ref={(ref) => { this.nav = ref; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
         const getCurrentRouteName = (navigationState) => {
         if (!navigationState) return null;
         const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
         if (route.routes) return getCurrentRouteName(route);
         return route.routeName;
    };
    global.currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
  }}
/>;
```